# EMV GET DATA using T0

Tags: apdu, emv

I am writing some firmware which uses (Sadly) T0 protocol to talk to some EMV Cards. All going well so far - I can select PSE, Select the AID, and Get processing options.
However, I am stumped on how to use GET DATA to read the PIN retry counter.

I send the APDU: {0x80, 0xCA, 0x9F, 0x17} then a 0 byte for LE, as per the spec. This gives me a 0x6c  (Length error), and a value of 4 for LE. So I re-issue the APDU as: {0x80, 0xCA, 0x9F, 0x17, 0x04}

When I read the procedure byte, after this second APDU send, it's 0xCA, which, if I understand T0 correctly, is just an ACK of the APDU header.

So, I can't see how to get the actual data for Data item 0x9F17.

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: As far as I know if card responds with PCB=INS it means you send case 3 command, but GET DATA is case 2,  and case 2 commands don't implement PCB. Case 2 APDUs respond with data and SW without PCB.

Comment: @nvf What is PCB?

Comment: @Greycon You should receive more bytes as procedure byte should be followed by four data bytes and two bytes with status.

Comment: @Greycon I mean PB (procedure byte)

Comment: @nvf - Spot on - I did a receiveData for 6 more bytes and gikt what I needed. If you want to add an answer to this effect, I will be happy to accept it. Cheers